# How to call a function in a php file using jquery load?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to display the data i retrieve from the database but it is not being displayed. I have a function in the file getComments.php called "getComments(page)" page is just a integer parameter to choose that database. and as you can see that i need to call this function to print the users comments. I am trying to use "load" but it is not being successful i just want to call this function to load the comments on the page. thank you in advance.

```
<?php

use TastyRecipes\Controller\SessionManager;
use TastyRecipes\Util\Util;

require_once '../../classes/TastyRecipes/Util/Util.php';
Util::init();

function getComments($page){
   echo "<br><br>";
   $controller = SessionManager::getController();
   $controller->getComments($page);
   SessionManager::setController($controller);
}
```

and in my web page where i want to display it using java script, i tried the following

```
<div class="page" id="comments">
  <p class="style">Comments</p>
  <button class="btn" id="load-comments">See Previous Comments</button><br> 
  <br><br>

  <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['u_id'])){
       echo "  <input type='hidden' id='uid' value = '".$_SESSION['u_uid']."'>
          <input type='hidden' id='date' value = '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
          <textarea id='message'></textarea><br>
          <button class = 'btn' type = 'submit' id = 'submitCom'>Comment</button>";
    }
    else{
      echo "<p>Please log in to comment</p>";
    }
   ?>
</div><br>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#load-comments").click(function(){
     document.getElementById('#comments').innerHTML = 
    $("#comments").load("../extras/getComments.php", getComments(1));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: remove # inside getElementById or use jquery instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `click` handler to this:

```
$("#load-comments").click(function(){
    $("#comments").load("../extras/getComments.php", { page: 1 }); //i also added where the elements are loaded
});
```

and in `getComments.php` (if practical, otherwise you might need to create a new PHP file which calls the `getComments()` function and call that from the click handler instead) add something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['page'])) {
    getComments($_POST['page']);
    // do any other necessary stuff
    exit;
}
```